# How can i assign value when creating a column of a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
alter table tablename add column mark tinyint NOT NULL;
```

I want to assign 1 as a default value of that mark column .

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alter table tablename add column mark tinyint default 1 NOT NULL;
```